# Problem with CHARSET in MySQL create table

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Hi this is my code and it returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUE, chapter VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLA' at line 2"

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS texts (
>                               id SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE,
>                               chapter VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
>                               text LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
>                               uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY,
>                               time TIMESTAMP,
>                               FULLTEXT (chapter)
>                               )Engine = InnoDB;

I have no idea what is wrong, I was writing it according to MySQL documentation.

I also tried changing this column to

> chapter VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8, 
>   ...

but it returned the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
id SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE,
```

is invalid. You need to specify a value for DEFAULT VALUE or take it out.

```
id SERIAL,
```

However you have 2 auto_increment fields in your table which is also invalid. Serial is just an alias for

```
BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT .
```

Comment: Good answer.  I think "VALUE" doesn't belong there either.  No need to set a default value for an auto-increment column anyway.